group cohomology question
It's well known that an exact sequence 0 -> A -> B -> H -> 1 of groups (with A abelian) yields an exact sequence 0 -> A -> M -> IH -> 0 of H-modules, where IH is the augmentation ideal in the integral group ring of H. Not often mentioned is this detail:
(1) An isomorphic copy of B can be built in a natural way from the elements of M that map to elements of IH of the form h-1.
(1) is not hard to prove; e.g. if you look at p. 120 of Mac Lane's classic text Homology, the proof is in plain sight. (In his notation, the isomorphic copy of B consists of elements [b]+L in M, and the isomorphism is defined by the obvious correspondence b <-> [b]+L.) However Mac Lane does not actually mention (1); nor does any other textbook I've looked at. Does anyone know of an algebraic reference that mentions (1) explicitly?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
